# Swift can't see second module's header

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode

We have a swift module that imports and obj-c module and that works fine.

BUT if a swift module imports a obj-c module that imports another obj-c module, swift can’t see the second module’s headers

Anyone seen this happen before?

---

detail:

I created a module called ModelFoundation that has a protocol that other modules can assume our models conform to so they don’t deal directly with PIModel.

Now ExperimentManager complains when it imports PIModels saying it can’t find ModelFoundation.h (imported by a file in PIModels)

If in the PIModel module file I import ModelFoundation via #import "my/path/to/ModelFoundation/ModelFoundation.h" then it works

note: maybe has to do with how I built. we use xchammer making xcode project